# Refactor with pyCharm from "user" to "self.user"

Tags: python, refactoring, pycharm

I want to move a variable from local scope to object level. The new code should use `self.user` and not `user` like before:

```
class Foo(object):
    def test_foo(self):
        user=User()
        ...
        user.do()
```

New code should look like:

```
class Foo(object):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.user=User() # I can remove this line by hand
        ...
        self.user.do()
```

I tried to refactor>>rename from `user` to `self.user` but pyCharm says: "Inserted identifier is not valid"

How can I refactor this with pyCharm?

Comment: This is indeed a bizarre glitch in pycharm

Answer (score 13):

What you are trying to do is *not* a simple rename, but creating a new *instance attribute*.
As such, instead of using *Rename* you should use *Extract > Field* menu item.
Alternatively you can access this refactoring as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (this depends on the shortcuts you have chosen. Mine is the default for KDE).

Comment: Help me understand how *Extract > Field* works.  It changes the variable from, say, *foo* to *self.foo* at the point where is it invoked, but as far as I can tell it doesn't change it anywhere else in the code.  Also, when I invoke it on, say, *bar*, the text entry field opens with *self.l* and I have to retype *bar*.   Something tells me that I'm not understanding it correctly.  What I want is to replace *foo* with *foo.bar* at all of the appropriate places in the code without having to do an error-prone *Find/Replace"

Comment: PyCharm has no way of knowing that a local variable, with the same name, is meant to be treated in the same way as one that you are renaming. You could have a `user` in a different function that references something different. As far as I know what you want is a find & replace. You can make PyCharm ask for confirmation if you want to be sure.

Comment: This is a pretty major limitation of pycharm, as this is not some refactoring corner case, but a pretty common one. Sort of left scratching my head.

Comment: @neuronet I don't see **any** case in which this refactoring would happen in real life. Local variables *are local*, so you cannot access them from outside the function that defines them. Extract Field does extract all the uses of a local *in that function*, which are the only relevant ones. No IDE provide any kind of functionality similar to this because what the OP wants does not fit in any meaningful refactoring category, it's a plain Find&replace where you manually choose which cases you want to replace.

Comment: @Bakuriu if it replaces all uses within the Class, that should be fine. I thought you were saying it wouldn't do that.