# Refactoring variable to monkey-patched attribute in PyCharm

Tags: python, ide, refactoring, pycharm, rename

In Pycharm a segment of my code in the editor looks like this:

```
q = slice(0, 6)

q1 = 0
q2 = 1
q3 = 2
q4 = 3
q5 = 4
q6 = 5
```

But now I want to do:

```
q.q1 = 0
q.q2 = 1
q.q3 = 2
q.q4 = 3
q.q5 = 4
q.q6 = 5
```

So that these variables are now monkey-patched attributes of `q`. These are used in several places in my project so I'd like to refactor. First I tried highlighting `q1` then going `Refactor->Rename...` and then changing the name to `q.q1`, however this gives me the message, `"'q.q1' is not a valid identifier"`.

Is there any way in PyCharm to do this type of refactor? I tried doing a simple find and replace but there are a lot of other function names that contain `q1` and this is only a subset of the refactoring that I need to do. I know that I could use a regex to do this but am wondering if there is any other way?

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929250/refactor-with-pycharm-from-user-to-self-user), this actually isn't a simple refactor like it sounds.

You're two main options are: 1) To try and use the Refactor -> Extract option instead or 2) to use a Find and Replace (I appreciate that's far more manual and potentially time consuming!).

I'm not sure how well the Extract option works with monkey patched variables like yours. I'll investigate further.

Comment: I've never had to use extract before, but looking [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/extract-method.html) I'm not sure how it would apply to this case yet.

Comment: Yes having just revisited it to test it out, I don't think it's suitable here. From what I can see you are indeed stuck with the more manual approach (or a RegEx like you mention).