# Is there any easier way to do this? Pycharm query

Tags: python, pycharm

So I was making my voice assistant made with python more efficient but I'm stuck at a time-consuming problem.[image]

I've given the image. Is there any way to replace the variable "cmd" with the variable "query" in all lines with just some clicks? Changing the variable one by one takes up a lot of time.

Comment: `for op in [cmd, query]:` then use `op` in place of `cmd`.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/rename-symbol/

Comment: vscode has multi-line cursors

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25929250

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Pycharm you can highlight an occurrence of cmd in your code, right click on it, select Refactor, Rename.

You can now choose a new name and a scope for the files in which Pycharm should search and carry out the replacement in. Make sure you know the implications of where this replacement will be done, because you could accidentally refactor the term "cmd" in locations you didn't mean to.